# diffing linux and solaris files to local windows file over ssh/scp

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, diff

There are two remote machines, one with redhat linux, the other with solaris. Each has a file (let's say /var/log/events.log) that is rotated daily, can be from 0 bytes to 400Mb in size and is updated constantly. There is a third machine with windows xp, that should monitor updates to that file which is currently done by an ssh session opened with putty and tail -f /var/log/events.log running in it.

There are some restrictions on how it should be done:

1. I can't use anything except SSH and SCP for remote access.
2. The solution must **NOT** require installing, storing or having running permanently anything on the remote servers; it should operate with single connection attempts.
3. It should have minimal impact on network load, close to that of a remotely executed tail -f

I've looked up how diffing is usually done and found out about rsync. Unfortunately, solaris server doesn't have it installed, and on redhat server, I don't have permissions to launch it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your issue? It seems like you've described your solution in the first paragraph.

Comment: I need to automate this to generate events based on what tail captures, so I need to sync remote and local outputs. Also, tail -f doesn't comply with pt.2, in "not require anything running permanently on the remote servers" part. I need to get the same I get with tail -f, but automatically and without constantly maintaining a session.

Comment: So what is your specific problem? You need to copy a file from a remote system over ssh, and you don't have rsync? How about sftp or scp?

Comment: The file is too large to copy, so I need to diff it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather old, but it seems that you want to use `rsync`.

According to Wikipedia:

> rsync is a file synchronization and file transfer program for Unix-like systems that minimizes network data transfer by using a form of delta encoding called the rsync algorithm.

So you can synchronize the files by they diff, thus saving a lot of bandwidth and time.

Official rsync page is [here](http://rsync.samba.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately, rsync requires installation on the remote machine. That won't do: I need a command-line utility that will connect via ssh, then compare target file size with the one on local side, and then download the difference. For example, I have **c:\messages** on the local machine, and **/var/log/messages** on the remote. I need something to connect to the remote machine via ssh or scp, check if **/var/log/messages** is different from local **c:\messages** and then, if remote file's bigger than local, update local with whatever was added, without re-downloading the whole file.

Comment: The trick is, it must be done without installing or otherwise permanently storing anything on the remote machine.